# application failed codesign verification

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to submit my app,
and getting the "Application failed codesign verification"

I'm guessing it's because I don't have a distribution provision profile yet,
but iOS Provisioning Portal won't let me make one.
When I click on submit, it does nothing.
I've tried it on different computers, different browsers, but the same.

Is it absolutely necessary to have a distribution provision profile,
or does it suffice to have a development provision profile?

I believe I have done everything else correctly, such as entlitments.plist, bundle identifier, etc.

Please please help me out!

Comment: btw I do have a distribution certificate.. but not provisioning profile

Comment: It might be more than obvious to everybody in Apple world, but you could mention where you're submitting your application.

Comment: my apology. it's an ipad app.

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just asking.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do anything without a Distribution profile so I would concentrate on solving that problem first.

Comment: could it be because I didn't configure my app ID for apple push notification services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Distribution Profile Name is different to the Development Profile Name.

I usually go for:

```
Development Provisioning Profile Name:
  My App Name

Distribution Provisioning Profile Name:
  My App Name Dist
```

Comment: omg....  can't believe it was that simple thing that wasted my hours... thank you so much!!!